# Django textile make a link both red and bold

Tags: python, django, textile

I want to make this `"*<span style="color:#ff0000">Text</span>*":http://www.example.com/lifestyle/tpage2` in textile become bold and red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<strong>` tags, like `"*<span style="color:#ff0000"><strong>Text</strong></span>*":http://www.example.com/lifestyle/tpage2`